# Kivy Python & Server socket.error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: android, python, sockets, kivy

I wanted to make an kivy App, that runs on android and communicates with an Server, that runs on an Ubuntu PC.
When I ran it on QPython everything was fine, but when I tried it with an App, that I compiled with buildozer, I got the Error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Here is the Server:

```
import socket
import errno


def Main():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 12345

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(1)


    while True:

        c, addr = s.accept()
        c.setblocking(0)

        print "Connection from: " + str(addr)


        command = c.recv(1024)

        if command == 'GIVETEXT':
            c.send('test')

        try:
            c.close()
            #s.setsockopt(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 1)
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        except socket.error as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
                raise
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

And Here is the client.py, the ip and ports are passed in in the main.py, that works fine:

```
import socket

class Client(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def sent(self, host, port):
        self.s.connect((host, port))
        self.s.send('GIVETEXT')#sends command

        self.recived_string = self.s.recv(1023)

        print self.recived_string

        self.s.close
        return self.recived_string
```

I also gave the App, the permission "Internet".

Here is the Importand Part of the spec file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Server Test Applicaton

# (str) Package name
package.name = mytest

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

#
# iOS specific
#
#[...]
[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

#[...]
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing spec file? I'm not sure if it checks only uppercase, but spec should explain more.

Comment: Spec seems good to me. Just a wild guess, but try to add sdcard permissions too? Otherwise, don't have a clue why if it works in qpython. You don't need other permissions such as bluetooth that qpy has. Do you by any chance use different python that qpython uses(e.g. py3 or different py2)?